# Deserialize Liferay ServiceBuilder Models in JAX-RS REST Endpoint

Tags: jackson, liferay, liferay-7, jackson-databind

We are using Liferay ServiceBuilder for object persistence and we need now to offer a JAX-RS Rest API using a `JaxrsWhiteboard` Application.
This is basically not a problem, but I want to use my service models for PUT and POST operations.

As we only have -api dependency, only the model interfaces are visible for our methods.
Because the Deserializer can not instantiate Java interface, we hooked in a `DeserializationProblemHandler.handleMissingInstantiator` to the Jackson mapper that instantiate interface implementation using the createXX operations of the service.

This also works, but the deserialization does not take place. The service gets an empty object that does not contain the data from the request. It looks like the `BeanDeserializer` was not used.

Does anyone had tried to implement this already? What needs to be configured in code to implement a Jax-RS API with ServiceBuilder models?

Answer (score 0):

As time passes, I found a solution I want to share for everyone trying to do the same thing.
I found out that Liferay internally uses Jodd as a json parser, so I replace Jackson with Jodd in my `Application.getSingletons` call using a custom `MessageBodyReader<PersistedModel>`.
The `jodd.json.JsonParser` has an protected method `newObjectInstance(Class targetType)` that I overwrote in my derived class to return servicebuilder model instances using the XXLocalServiceUtil.createXX() factory methods.

My MessageBodyReader than uses my derived JsonParser via:

```
// important to use the XXModel interface,
// as Jodd uses only declared setter on deserialization
parser.parse(bodyJSON, XXModel.class);
```

Using this, ServiceBuilder interface models can be used in the REST Api of jax-rs whiteboard.